# Send form data (string) and array through AJAX jQuery form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've researched several similar answers however I can't find any that show how to send **both** an array, *and* a string.

I have discovered that `.serialize` and `.serializeArray` should allow me to construct the string I need to send the form data and the array to my PHP script, but I cannot understand the syntax to use both of these functions together.

My form is simple:

```
<form id="email-input">
   <input type="email" name="user-mail" />
</form>
```

I wish to submit with AJAX, and send both the value in the form *and* a javascript array called `basketData` to my PHP script.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/send-mail.php",
            data: {$("#email-input").serialize(),basketData.serializeArray()}
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

I'm aware the above is completely syntactically incorrect but I just can't work out how to pass multiple data values through this function.

Comment: What is `basketData`? Why do you need to use the two functions together?

Comment: @Quentin as specified in the OP it is an array. I need to use this array of data in my PHP script.

Comment: You can't call `serializeArray` as a method on an array, it isn't an array method.

Comment: Why don't you just create a JSON object out of all of this ?

Comment: What data do you actually have? How is your PHP trying to read it from the request?

Comment: @Quentin I have a string from the form above, and this multidimensional array. I wish to read these in PHP (using _POST I guess) so I can use them in my PHP script.

Comment: @V.Roudge if that is the best method please advise with an answer.

Comment: Send as `data: {formData: $("#email-input").serialize(), otherData:basketData.serializeArray()}` then receive in PHP appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/send-mail.php",
    data: {
        email: $('input[name="user-mail"]').val(),
        basketData: basketData
    }
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$basketData = $_POST['basketData'];
```

Comment: Wasn't actually me who downvoted, but this doesn't work sadly. Though the array part works great, it fails to get any value from the input field. I believe this is because `.val()` is used on the `form#email-input` which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @user1486133: try it now. I made a mistake with the email input.

Comment: I still get nothing for `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: Got there in the end. The correct selector is `name="user-email"`

Comment: @user1486133: glad I could help :)

Comment: @user1486133 — Not with the HTML in the question. The field has `name="user-mail"`

Answer (score 0):

`serializeArray` is for converting a jQuery object containing a form into structured data as a precursor for converting it in to a serialized string. It is rarely useful to call it directly, and it can't be called on an array (`otherData:basketData.serializeArray()}` will throw an array because `serializeArray` is undefined since `basketData` isn't a jQuery object).

`serialize` is for converting a jQuery object containing a form into a string of form encoded data. It is great for dealing with complex forms. It becomes a little fiddly when you want to modify the data.

Forget about using either of them for this.

The `data` argument for `.ajax` accepts a JavaScript object as its value, and then jQuery will encode it as form data using PHP's conventions for complex data structures (which works out nicely for you since you say your array isn't flat and you are using PHP).

Just put the array and the *value* of the *form control* into your data object.

```
data: {
    email: $("input[name='user-mail']").val(),
    array: basketData
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the answer. Can you show how the values can be used in the PHP script as I'm currently getting nothing from `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: @user1486133 — That works fine for me: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAM-HlizCzlEzIJ7nFc-l1jGblmvqAQ9jiw